# Firestore merge does not return a Pormise

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing to Firestore per guidelines here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data and setting the `merge:true` option, however, this doesn't return a promise? Because of that we cannot chain `.then()` or `.catch()` with this flag turned on.

How can we know for sure it has completed the set/merge operation then?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the `{merge: true}` option with the [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set) method does not change the behavior of the method in terms of what it returns. As explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set) the method **does return a Promise**:

> **Returns:** non-null Promise containing void. A promise that resolves once the
>   data has been successfully written to the backend. (Note that it won't
>   resolve while you're offline).

So, unless you are offline, you can very well do as follows:

```
db.collection("cities").doc("LA").set({
    name: "Los Angeles",
    state: "CA",
    country: "USA"
},
{merge: true})
.then(function() {
    // ->>> Here you can be sure that "it has completed the set/merge operation"
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
});
```